# Elastica: Best way to check if document with Id x exists?

Tags: elastica

Using the PHP Elastica library, I'm wondering what is the best way to check whether a document with Id=1 exists?

I was doing as follows:

```
$docPre = $elasticaType->getDocument(1);
if ($docPre) {
    //do some stuff...
} else {
    //do something else...
}
```

However, the above code does not work because a NotFoundException is thrown by the getDocument() method if the document does not exist.

Alternatively, I could do a type "search" using something like this:

```
$elasticaQueryString = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
$elasticaQueryString->setParam('id', 1);
$elasticaQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
$elasticaQuery->setQuery($elasticaQueryString);
$resultSet = $elasticaType->search($elasticaQuery);
$count = $resultSet->count();
if ($count > 0) {
    //do some stuff...
} else {
    //do something else...
}
```

However, the above seems quite cumbersome... What's the better way?
[This other question applies to ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059041/fancy-efficient-way-of-checking-if-a-document-exists-at-elasticsearch), and one of the answers suggests my first approach (the equivalent to using getDocument). However, I do not want an Exception to be thrown, as it would be the case using Elastica...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than preventing the Exception from being thrown, one way would be to simply deal with it with a "Try, throw and catch" block like this:

```
try {
    $docPre = $elasticaType->getDocument(1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $docPre = NULL;
}
if ($docPre != NULL) {
    //do some stuff...
} else {
    //do something else...
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I had to do like this: catch (\Elastica\Exception\NotFoundException $e) {